# stl predicate with different types

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector of ordered container classes where I need to know the index of the container that has a given element

so, I would like to do the following, but this obviously doesn't work. I could create a dummy Container to house the date to find, but I was wondering if there was a nicer way.

```
struct FooAccDateComp 
{
  bool operator()(const Container& d1, const MyDate&  f1) const 
  { return   d1->myDate < f1; } 
};

class Container
{
   MyDate myDate;
   ...
};

vector<Container> mystuff; 
MyDate temp(2008, 3, 15);

//add stuff to variable mystuff

int index = int(upper_bound(events.begin(), events.end(),temp, FooAccDateComp())-events.begin());
```

EDIT: The container class can contain other dates.

Comment: Change upper_bound to find_if, and it should work just fine. That said, why aren't you using a map here?

Comment: @Billy: a sorted vector can be faster than a map, if you don't change it very often.

Comment: @Billy: the complexities are way different, `upper_bound` is O(log N) while `find_if` is O(N).

Comment: @Billy, I'm actually using the upper_bound property. It will return the index of the element that is not greater than what I'm looking for. So, my date doesn't necessarilly match up to what is in the container.

Comment: @Matthieu: I wasn't saying that it'd be a perfect solution; only that it would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`upper_bound` needs to be able to evaluate expressions like `Comp(date,container)`, but you've only provided `Comp(container,date)`. You'll need to provide both:

```
struct FooAccDateComp 
{
    bool operator()(const Container& c, const MyDate& d) const 
        { return c.myDate < d; } 

    bool operator()(const MyDate& d, const Container& c) const 
        { return d < c.myDate; } 
};
```

Remember that the vector must be sorted according to this comparison for `upper_bound` and friends to work.

Comment: Gasp, you've been faster :p I just wanted to add that `upper_bound` doesn't necessarily returns `Container` with the given date, it returns the first element with a date equals OR GREATER. You'll need to test, afterwards, if you reached the end and (if not) if the date is effectively what you wanted (there might not be such container in the vector).

Comment: I tried this and it still complains about not being able to "convert parameter 2 from const Container& to const Date&". I'm using VS2008. Does this work on your end? I agree it looks like it should work

Comment: @Steve: I did a quick test with GCC before answering, and all was fine. I don't have a copy of VS available, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a special predicate, just enable comparison between Container and MyDate.

```
#include <vector>

struct MyDate {
   MyDate(int, int, int);
};

struct Container {
   MyDate myDate;
};

// enable comparison between Container and MyDate
bool operator<(Container const&, MyDate const&);
bool operator==(Container const&, MyDate const&);

std::vector<Container> v; 
//add stuff to variable mystuff
MyDate temp(2008, 3, 15);
std::vector<Container>::iterator i = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), temp);
ptrdiff_t index = i != v.end() && *i == temp ? i - v.begin() : -1;
```

Comment: A dedicate predicate is much better, really. Consider the case where you have several dates within the `Container`, which one would you compare to ?

Comment: Add complexity only if you need to. In this example it seems unnecessary.

Comment: there are actually other dates in the container. I'll update the question

Comment: in this case you do need a functor

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_if` if you don't mind degrading performance (you said that you have a vector of sorted `Container`, so binary search would be faster)
Or you can add

```
struct Container {
    MyDate myDate;
    operator MyDate () {return myDate}; 
}
bool operator <(MyDate  const&, MyDate const&)
{
  return // your logic here
};
```

Now you can use binary search functions

`std::vector<Container>::iterator i = std::upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), MyDateObject);`

Surely, it will work only if your vector is sorted by `Container.myDate`

Comment: I assume you mean `operator MyDate()`. It's usually best to avoid conversion operators if you can; they can mask errors that would otherwise be caught by the compiler. Also, this gives an unnecessary copy on each comparison.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. It definitely should have been `operator MyDate()`. Fixed. Thanks for pointing this

Answer (score 0):

Your example is broken in several trivial ways: the class `Container` should be defined before `FooAccDateComp` in order for it to be used there, you should make `myDate` a *public* member of `Container`, access that member in the comparison method using `.myDate` rather than `->myDate`, and finally decide whether to call your vector `mystuff` or `events`, but not mix both. I'll suppose that appropriate corrections have been made.

You should have defined your comparison function to take a `Date` parameter as first argument and a `Container` parameter as second; the opposite to what you did. Or you could use `std::lower_bound` instead of `std::upper_bound` if that would suit you purpose (since you don't say what you are going to do with `index` it is hard to tell) as the choice made in the question is adapted to that. Contrary to what the currently accepted answer says you do not need both if you are only using `std::upper_bound` or only `std::lower_bound` (though you would need both if using `std::equal_range`, or when using both `std::upper_bound` and `std::lower_bound`).

You can find these at first sight a bit strange specifications in the standard, but there is a way to understand without looking it up why they have to be like this. When using `lower_bound`, you want to find the point that separates the `Container` entries that are (strictly) less than your given `Date` from those that are not, and this requires calling the comparison function with that `Date` argument in second position. If however you ask for an `upper_bound` (as you are), you want to find the point that separates the entries that are not strictly *greater* than your given `Date` from those that are, and this requires calling the comparison function with that `Date` argument in first position (and negating the boolean result it returns). And for `equal_range` you of course need both possibilities.